How to use >select(fields list and relation in 1 eloquent request?
On laravel 10 site making request from Post table(which has a lot of columns I got also related creator table :
        $postList = Post
            ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->with('creator')
            ->get();

and I have access to
$post->creator->name

field. I try to reduce number requested fields with fields list :
        $postList = Post
            ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->with('creator')
            ->select('id', 'title', 'slug', 'published', 'created_at')

But in this case I see error as $post->creator is null
and in sql - tracement I see fields listed
   SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `published`, `created_at`
    FROM `post`
    ORDER BY `created_at` desc

If there is a way to use  >select(fields list and relation in 1 request ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.4",

Thanks in advance!

From my understanding, eagger loading is not dessigned to be used like this. You could achieve what you want with a query joining the creator's table. Or you can just get a column in the relation: ->with('creator.name').  Let me know if those options would do the job for you.

Combining                ->with('creator.name') and   ->select('id', 'title', 'slug', 'published', 'created_at'   in one request does not work and I got the same runtime error when refering $post->creator->name 

I would be happy to help you if you share more information. If $post->creator->name is not working as intended I could think that either the ->get() is missing (so you're working with a query builder), the relation is not build properly or there are posts without creator. In the last case null safe operator would solve the issue.

->with('creator.name') wouldn't work... Dot-notation in a with() is how you load nested relationships, like Country::with('state.city')->get() is how you'd eager load all countries with their associated state and nested city. You're probably looking for Eager Load Specific Columns, so you'd do Post::with('creator:id,name')->select('id', 'title', 'slug', 'published', 'created_at')->get(), but read the warning on that page and make sure to always include 'creator:id, ...' and other related columns.

When you're explicitly defining columns on your queries and loading relationships you have always to make sure that the keys whose those relationships depend are also defined. E.g.:
        $postList = Post::select(
                'id',
                'creator_id', // fk to Creator model
                'title',
                'slug',
                'published',
                'created_at',
            )
            ->with('creator:id,name,other_columns...') // now related creators can be matched
            ->latest()
            ->get();

